# How to create a Class inside of a namespace?

Tags: c++, class, header-files

What must the structure of a class look like if it is defined in a separate namespace?

Which parts belong in the header file and which in the cpp file?

How can I make the class accessible only through this specific namespace?

Comment: The structure of the class, and how the class is accessed, doesn't change just because it is in a namespace. The class declaration (inside a namespace declaration) belongs in the header file. The class implementation belongs in the cpp file. Namespaces don't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**classname.h**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N {
    class classname {
    public:
        void classmethod();
    }
}
```

**classname.cpp**

```
#include "classname.h"

namespace N {
    void classname::classmethod() {
        std::cout << "classmethod" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "classname.h"

int main() {
    N::classname a;
    classname b; // Error!

    a.classmethod();

    return 0;
}
```